# SKMaps / Skobbler Map Server Down

Tags: ios, skmaps, skobbler-maps

One or some of the SKMaps/Skobbler Map Servers appears to be down, since 2 days ago. Is this just me or are more people experiencing this? If it's just me any help would be appreciated in how I could resolve this.

I'm updating my iOS app from SKMaps Framework version 2.5.1 to 3.0. which also includes updated maps. I had my app working with 3.0. Then I also started to update my app to Swift 3.0 and updated to Xcode 8.0. Have not been able to get it working since. It runs, but map server seems unreachable. I'm not sure if the update to Swift3/Xcode8 could be the reason.

**
UPDATE:
I tried now NOT updating the Map Version (so keep using the 201504 maps) and everything works fine. So it doesn't appear to be related to updating to Swift3/Xcode8. It seems the map server for the 201604 maps is acting up. **

There were some confirmed map server issues last week, but [they were resolved](http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/8086-Metadata-not-being-loaded-upon-framework-initialisation) . Not sure if that problem occurred again?

Basically my app is useless at this moment. MetaData can't be downloaded, Online Map tiles are not retrieved/displayed, Offline Map Packages can nog be downloaded, Search is not working, Online Route Calculation not working, etc.

Here's the most telling console log piece. I get this when trying to download the JSON with the Offline Map Regions:

```
[AnyHashable("Content-Type"): application/xml, AnyHashable("Connection"): keep-alive, AnyHashable("Date"): Wed, 21 Sep 2016 17:51:58 GMT, AnyHashable("X-Amz-Cf-Id"): zBW5kFdCN-9fhZnpj8WyeL7CCx2eEEixO9BPIDGbyJHxqAuFa8gf9Q==, AnyHashable("Transfer-Encoding"): Identity, AnyHashable("Server"): AmazonS3, AnyHashable("Via"): 1.1 01448657fc099ab201797422a6a02be2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), AnyHashable("X-Cache"): Error from cloudfront]
```

When trying to download the meta files upon framework initialisation I get this:

```
the resource not found: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/roads
offline mode, the resource cannot be downloaded: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/roads
the resource not found: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/attributes
offline mode, the resource cannot be downloaded: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/attributes
the resource not found: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/elevations
offline mode, the resource cannot be downloaded: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/elevations
the resource not found: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/version.txt
offline mode, the resource cannot be downloaded: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/version.txt
the resource not found: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/bikeAttributes
offline mode, the resource cannot be downloaded: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/bikeAttributes
the resource not found: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/shapes
offline mode, the resource cannot be downloaded: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/shapes
the resource not found: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/pois
offline mode, the resource cannot be downloaded: /Users/guido/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1CF279C5-7F13-4379-A1C2-268C290D0B56/data/Containers/Data/Application/44D9119E-6DF3-4133-92F0-DF738199826B/Library/Caches/maps/v1/20160426/meta/pois
```

I'm sure I have connection and I'm sure i'm in online mode as this is my framework initialisation code:

```
let initSettings: SKMapsInitSettings = SKMapsInitSettings()
initSettings.mapDetailLevel = SKMapDetailLevel.Light    // Same thing if I change this to .Full
initSettings.connectivityMode = SKConnectivityMode.Online
initSettings.showConsoleLogs = true
SKMapsService.sharedInstance().initializeSKMapsWithAPIKey(SKMapsAPIKey, settings: initSettings)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It's very likely Skobbler's '**light**/v1/20160426' API endpoint.

- If I switch the 3.0 demo project to the ‘light’ map, it doesn’t work either (no meta data downloaded, no online maps visible, no offline map json downloaded, etc.)
- If I switch my app to the ‘full’ map, all is working ok.

Have been in contact with the devs at Skobbler and imagine they will fix this quickly.

Comment: The 3.0 version does not have "light" maps yet - this is what is causing the issue. Please switch to using "full" maps